# Typescript error TS2339: Property 'webkitURL' does not exist on type 'Window'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typescript, angular, webkit

Using Angular 2 on a project which is compiled with typescript.

Getting this error when trying to create a blob image:

`error TS2339: Property 'webkitURL' does not exist on type 'Window'`

ts code is:

`public url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
this.photo = this.url.createObjectURL( res );`

Comment: `webkitURL` is deprecated.

Answer (score 53):

> error TS2339: Property 'webkitURL' does not exist on type 'Window'

The lib.d.ts does not ship with stuff that is browser specific. However you can easily do `(window as any).webkitURL`. This is called a [type assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html).

## More

- [docs on lib.d.ts](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html)
- [Quick migration tips](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html)

The common `(as any)` style type assertion is a quickfix provided by alm : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/alm/content/features/quickfix.html

Answer (score 10):

The solution that works as of TypeScript 2.1.5:

```
interface Window {
    webkitURL?: any;
}

declare var window: Window;

if (window.webkitURL !== undefined) {
    console.log(window.webkitURL);
}
```

In the above code we declared an interface/shape for Window which will optionally have webkitURL defined and then we do a check to make sure it is defined.

Answer (score -1):

This approach worked for me. My curren version of typescript is 2.0.3

add this out of the class

```
 interface Window { logged_user: Object }
```

and when you need use this property, just use it

```
window.logged_user = {};//your data
```

Answer (score -3):

Solution 1:

```
interface Window {
  webkitURL: any;
}

declare var window: Window;

 //Now typescript will not throw any error on window.webkitURL
```

Solution 2: 
`(<any>window).webkitURL` does not throw ts error